# how to write a script whoser output & input can be from/to a pipe?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdout, stdin

Simple question, but i have not found a clear & simple answer:

1. **How do I write a script whose output can be piped into another program?**

e.g.:    `my_script.sh  |  awk '{ whatever }'  |  ...`

2. **How do I write a script who receives input from a pipe?**

e.g.:   `awk '{ whatever }' some_file  |  my_script.sh`

Are `stdout` and `stdin` what is used for "pipe out to another program" and "pipe in from another program"?

I intend to pipe in & out large text files (10Mb to several Gb).  Is `echo` or `cat` the right utility to use within `my_script.sh` to pipe out?

Similarly, is `while read line; do   ..... done` the right thing to use for receiving input from a pipe in?  I would like to use `awk` or `sed` most of the time on the input to `my_script.sh`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: As long as the program produces STDOUT it can go on the left. As long as it can take STDIN it can go on the right. Thats pretty much the only rule.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples both concern this pipeline, where you want a script to stand in for one or the other:

```
awk '{ whatever }' some_file | awk '{ whatever }'
```

To do this, you just put each of the commands in a file:

`producer`:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ whatever }' some_file
```

`consumer`:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ whatever }'
```

Now you can run #1:

```
producer  |  awk '{ whatever }'  |  ...
```

And you can run #2:

```
awk '{ whatever }' some_file  |  consumer
```

And of course both at the same time:

```
producer | consumer
```

You should not fall into the trap of thinking you need to read data on `awk`'s behalf with a while read loop or similar. `awk` reads input and writes output by itself, so whenever you run it without any further specifications, it will inherit the script's stdin and stdout and work on those.

Comment: can those scripts `producer` and `consumer` be more complicated?  ie., can  i define shell variables, do some intermediate computations , and *then* call `awk` or something?

Comment: @cmo all the pipe does is takes the printed output from one side and feed it to the other.If you do variable assignment and don't output anything then it won't affect the other side.